# Full screen html5 player on IE11 not working

Tags: javascript, html

The full screen button is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla but when it comes to IE11 The full screen button is not working. Is their any way to get this?

```
function fscreen(){
    if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
        vid.requestFullscreen();
        //vid.controls = true;
    } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
        //vid.controls = true;
    } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        //vid.controls = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE11 `requestFullscreen` method is also prefixed. So you'll need to modify your function like this:

```
function fscreen(){
    if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
        vid.requestFullscreen();
        //vid.controls = true;
    } else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
        //vid.controls = true;
    } else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        //vid.controls = true;
    } else if(vid.msRequestFullscreen) {
        vid.msRequestFullscreen();
        //vid.controls = true;
    }
}
```